# Template specialization in case of multiple base templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have two template functions:

```
template<class X> void foo(X a)
{
    cout << "Template 1" << endl;
}


template<class X> void foo(X *a)
{
    cout << "Template 2" << endl;
}
```

Now, if I define a specialization such as:

```
template<> void foo<>(int *a)
{
    cout << "Specialization 1" << endl;
}
```

will this specialization belong to template 1 or template 2. Also, does it matter, if I define the specialization before or after template 2?

Comment: It is a especialization of template 2, as type X is int and the parameter is a pointer to type X.

Comment: @rbelli I have edited the question. What will be the outcome now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `X` with `int` and see which of the primary template yield a matching signature:

```
template<class X> void foo(X a)
```

becomes

```
template <> void foo<int>(int)
```

and

```
template<class X> void foo(X *a)
```

becomes

```
template<> void foo<int>(int *)
```

So, it can only be a specialization of the second function. Since the function doesn't specialize the first overload, it is necessary to declare the second primary template before you define a specialization because the specialization can't specialize the first primary template.

If the template argument is not explicitly specified in the specialization, the relevant primary template is found using the normal argument deduction rules according to 14.8.2.6 [temp.deduct.decl] paragraph 1:

> In a declaration whose declarator-id refers to a specialization of a function template, template argument deduction is performed to identify the specialization to which the declaration refers. Specifically, this is done for explicit instantiations (14.7.2),
>   explicit specializations (14.7.3), and certain friend declarations (14.5.4).

This argument deduction takes the partial ordering of the primary templates into account, i.e., it finds the second primary template. I didn't fall into the trap of reading the paragraph leading up to the limerick but the warning is real: I think you get into trouble if you change the order of the second primary template and the specialization! Beware the mentioned self-immolation warned about.

Comment: I have edited the question. What will happen if it instead is `template<> void foo<>(int *)`?

Comment: Interesting - I wasn't aware that you can leave out the argument for the specialization. I would expect that it basically detects the primary template to specialize by the same resolution as selecting the proper overload, i.e., I would expect that it specializes the second primary template. I would need to research that in the standard, though.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I have a question, why not the specialization could match template one by replace x with pointer of int, In another word, why this way has low priority to replacing x in template two with int?

Comment: @DarkHorse: The original question used `template <> void foo<int>(int*)` which can only be matched by the second primary template. When leaving out the first `int`, but primary templates can match and the specialized primary template is located using normal overload resolution and argument deduction which also finds the second primary template, though.

Comment: @DietmarKühl sorry for my poor English, I am still confused to follow your words. I want to say if template 1 replace x with int* that yield same result to replace with int in template 2. e.g. template<> void foo<int*> (int *), why this don't happend?

Comment: @DarkHorse: When template argument deduction and overload resolution kicks in, the compiler has two choices: `foo<int*>(int*)` and `foo<int>(int*)`. Each taken on their own do match. However, with both being present, overload resolution determines which one is a better match using partial ordering of function templates which is based on which one is more specialized: `foo<int>(int*)` is the more specialized version which is found. The rules for partial ordering for deduced function template overloads are complex enough to be a topic on themselves.

Comment: @DietmarKühl thank you very much, i may be get it now. Thanks